# android vibrator turn on and turn off

Tags: android, radio-button, vibration, ischecked

I'm making one part in my app where if you push the button then the phone will vibrate, and if you push the button again the phone will stop vibrating. I am using a Radio button for my button. my code is right now for the vibrate part:

```
                while(hard.isChecked()==true){
                    vt.vibrate(1000);
                }
```

The phone vibrates but it doesn't like vibrate with full power, and the radio button does not change. I am also unable to turn it off because the phone basically freezes. Anybody have any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried it myself. I think the code below is what you are looking for:

```
private Vibrator vibrator;
private CheckBox checkbox;
private Thread vibrateThread;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    vibrator = ((Vibrator)getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE));
    checkbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    vibrateThread = new VibrateThread();
}

public void onCheckBox1Click(View view) throws InterruptedException{
    if(checkbox.isChecked()){
        if (vibrateThread.isAlive()) {
            vibrateThread.interrupt();
            vibrateThread = new VibrateThread();
        } else {
            vibrateThread.start();
        }
    } else{
        vibrateThread.interrupt();
        vibrateThread = new VibrateThread();
    }
}

class VibrateThread extends Thread {
    public VibrateThread() {
        super();
    }
    public void run() {
        while(checkbox.isChecked()){                
            try {
                vibrator.vibrate(1000);
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here the layout:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:onClick="onCheckBox1Click"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You programmed an infinite loop. Your device has no chance to change the state of your Radio Button because it's still in the while-loop.

One possibility is to start the vibration-code in a separate thread.

Another possibility is to add a Thread.Sleep(100) or so in your while loop.

Comment: i want it to continually vibrate tho so would put tht thread.sleep make it so it cont. to vibrate.

Comment: I haven't tested it but as long as the sleep value is lower then the vibrate value it should work that way.

Comment: i tried but it still didn't work i think i may just do two buttons now  and have one cancel it and one start it. If you think of anything else please share.

Answer (score 1):

You are using while loop hard.isChecked() which will be true forever, now it loops into infinite loop. so use a break statement in the while loop

```
while(hard.isChecked()==true){
    vt.vibrate(1000);
break;
 }
```

or you can use the below code:

```
if(hard.isChecked()){
   vt.vibrate(1000);
}
```

Comment: well i want it to continually vibrate so if i put in the break or the if statement would that make it so the phone only vibrates once for 1000 milla seconds.